# Append extra null char to wide string

Tags: c, winapi, ole, widechar

Some Win32 API structures require to concatenate an extra null character to a string, as in the following example taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#cf_hdrop):

> c:\temp1.txt'\0'c:\temp2.txt'\0''\0'

When it comes to wide strings, what is the easiest way to append a L'\0' to the end of an existing wide string?

Here's what works for me but seems too cumbersome:

```
wchar_t my_string[10] = L"abc";
size_t len = wcslen(my_string);
wchar_t nullchar[1] = {'\0'};
memcpy(my_string + len + 1, nullchar, sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: assuming `my_string` is long enough `my_string[wcslen(my_string)+1]='\0'`?

Comment: That simple... and it even worked. Please post as a reply.

Comment: You tagged your question as `[c++]`, but your code seems more like C to me; e.g. in C++ you would use `std::wstring` (which is capable of storing embedded nulls), instead of raw `wchar_t` C-style arrays.

Comment: Fixed. @AlanBirtles please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming my_string is long enough:

```
my_string[wcslen(my_string)+1]='\0';
```

The terminating null will be translated to a wide char.

*(Posted as a first comment to the question)*

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 3):

In your example you can just assign the value just like any other array. There's nothing special about `wchar_t` here.

`my_string` already has a single null-termination, so if you want double null-termination, then just add another 0 after it.

```
wchar_t my_string[10] = L"abc";
size_t len = wcslen(my_string);
// todo: check out-of-bounds
my_string[len + 1] = 0;
```

Or even simpler, if it's really just a string literal,

```
wchar_t my_string[10] = L"abc\0";
```

This will be doubly-null-terminated.

Comment: in fact, it will even be sevenly-null-terminated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `std::wstring` instead of `wchar_t[]`, you can use its `operator+=` to append the extra null terminator, eg:

```cpp
wstring my_string = L"abc";
...
my_string += L'\0';
// use my_string.c_str() as needed...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the various paths in a `std::vector<std::wstring>`, you can just build the required format in a loop:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> paths;
paths.emplace_back(L""); // This empty path will add the extra NUL
std::wstring buf(1000, 0);
for (auto p : paths) {
    buf.append(p);
    buf.append(1, 0);
}
wchar_t *ptr = buf.c_str(); // Now do stuff with it
```